# FDA compliant online-marketing of products in the US

Tags: marketing

For a US site we have to market products for the research market. These products are helpful in medical applications but do not meet FDA requirements. Is a general disclaimer on the site sufficient to strike out non-FDA compliance, or do we have to mark every product with something like "for research only"? In addition, does this require e.g. to use only images without components that might be appropriate for FDA?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2009 I had to get certified by FDA for a Novartis job. Back in the day it was mandatory to every product that was only for research be marked as research only.  There have been updates for FDA compliance specially web/social midia.

I'm sure you will find all the information you need within this link.

http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/EnforcementActivitiesbyFDA/SelectedEnforcementActionsonUnapprovedDrugs/default.htm